# Get sheet name of .csv file in R

Tags: r, xlsx, read.csv, readr, readxl

Iam looking for a simplified way to read sheets names from .CSV files("challenges.csv" from readr_example(). ), this is what i have tried(with RStudio desktop) :

## list of sample files

> readr_example()
> [1] *"challenge.csv"*         "chickens.csv"          "epa78.txt"             "example.log"
> [5] "fwf-sample.txt"        "massey-rating.txt"     "mtcars.csv"            "mtcars.csv.bz2"
> [9] "mtcars.csv.zip"        "whitespace-sample.txt"

## list the names of the individual sheet "challenge.csv" with function read_excel()

> excel_sheets(readr_example("challenge.csv"))
> Error: Can't establish that the input is either xls or xlsx.

Someone have  a suggestion ??

Comment: csvs don't have sheets, you can see the raw data for those files [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/tree/main/inst/extdata), they are just text files

Comment: The simple way i found is  copy  R import dataset code, and modify it by adding read_csv instead of :

Comment: The simple way i found is  copy  R import dataset code, and modify it by adding read_csv() instead of read_excel() : library(readxl)
hotel_bookings <- read_csv("~/..../FileName")
View(FileName)